# PHP template (.tpl) how to exclude directories

Tags: php, templates

I'm using a PHP autoindex script which utilizes the template (.tpl) below.  I would like to open files only in a new tab.  I've tried adding target="_blank" to line 3 below, but this doesn't differentiate between files or directories and both open in a new tab.  I want to exclude directories from opening.

```
    <tr class="{file:tr_class}">
  <td class="padded_row">
   <a class="autoindex_a" href="{file:link}">
    {if:icon_path}<img width="16" height="16" alt="[{file:file_ext}]" src="{file:icon}" />{end if:icon_path}
    {file:filename} {file:thumbnail}
   </a>{file:new_icon}{file:md5_link}{file:delete_link}{file:rename_link}{file:edit_description_link}{file:ftp_upload_link}
  </td>
  {if:download_count}
  <td class="cell_right">
  {file:downloads}
  </td>
  {end if:download_count}
  <td class="cell_right">
   {file:size}
  </td>
  <!--<td class="cell_right">
   {file:date}
  </td> -->
  {if:description_file}
  <td class="padded_row">
  {file:description}
  </td>
  {end if:description_file}
 </tr>
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to check before opening the link like an "if statement". If it is a directory or file and then "do something"...however I'm not skilled in this area.
thanks for your help

Comment: Well, the templating language you're using clearly has `if` statements, because I can see them in the code sample. But ".tpl" is a common extension for lots of templating systems, so you'll have to find out which one it actually is. Once you do, you'll probably find it has some documentation, which may well answer your question.

Comment: As a side note, though, "is this URL a file or a directory?" isn't really a meaningful question - a URL is a string that a browser sends to a server and gets some content back. What you'll probably want to do is look at if the URL ends with `/`.

Comment: @IMSoP thank you, I have no idea what templating system was used, I presumed this was a php template written in PHP? And yes I too can see "if statements" as well, however I don't know how to write them in this instance.  You are correct, I checked the outputs and the directory output ends with "/", the file output does not.  However I'm still at a loss of how to write this as an if statement for this template?  thanks

Comment: No, this is not PHP, or a standard syntax that's part of PHP any way. It could just be a custom language built into whatever application you're customising. Without more details of what it is, nobody's going to be able to help you, I'm afraid.